# How to pass/onclick details to a new activity from RecyclerView? Firestore Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `Firestore` to store the data of the users,etc.

I would like to pass the data to a new activity which displays the respective details of the different users. This is the tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcSlckNifhkxbLCHWdahK28n .

Currently, I am able to set my intent on a `onClick` and go to my new activity from the recycler view but I am not able to see the respective details (an image and 2 textViews).

I have tried other solutions but it did not work.

Comment: How do I [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question?

Comment: Could you add code of all the activities related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to by pass information between intents you need to use the putExtra() function.
for example I want to pass the text from a Textview so after you initialize the intent 
you will need to use the putExtra, like this

```
Intent intent = new Intenet(this, *your desired activity*.class);
intent.putExtra("test",*variable here*);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the next activity you will need to get that information by using getExtra() function
so it will look like this

```
intent.getExtras().getString("test");
```

You can do the same thing for your images, just for images you will need to convert them to Bitmap .

```
yourImageviewID.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = yourImageviewID.getDrawingCache();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and when getting in the the next activity

```
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```